# How to hide custom Angular 12 selector in browser view

Tags: javascript, angular, angular12

I'm learning Angular 12 and I have some issues about the framework operation.
I've created a new project, added Bootstrap 5 and created some components.
When I nest a component inside another like this :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h2>Mes appareils</h2>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <app-appareil [appareilName]="appareilOne"></app-appareil>
        <app-appareil [appareilName]="appareilTwo"></app-appareil>
        <app-appareil [appareilName]="appareilThree"></app-appareil>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why I still see the custom selectors in the browser inspector view :
[Angular browser view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ags5p.png)

**It breaks several things in my Boostrap style.**

Did you know if it's possible to hide/remove these custom components of my browser view to get in this case only the `<li>` tags directly inside the `<ul>` instead of these `<app-appareil>` ?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't... Not a single video or tutorial I've seen ever remotely spoke about this. But you can add a class to you <app-appreil> component, just putting a class tag or through the component itself.

Comment: That is how angular works. But can you try `class="list-group-item"` in <app-appareil> and see if it works.

Comment: If I add a class directly on the custom HTML tag, it's also broken with Bootstrap.
Maybe it's an issue with CS frameworks ?

Comment: <app-appreil> is a dummy component and it does not break any style. Be specifc. Also a component is assumed to have multiple root elements. If one root element, then you can directly use it. Why you need app-appreil component?

Comment: To bind specific datas to each ```<app-appareil>``` component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-appareil"
})
```

to

```
@Component({
    selector: "li[appAppareil]"
})
```

and then use it as

```
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li appAppareil [appareilName]="appareilOne"></li>
  </ul>
```

By using an attribute selector we can avoid the wrapping component tag (which you cannot "remove"), and we preserve semantics of the DOM itself.

Likely to get better semantics you'd want to make further changes and use content projection, but that's unclear from the limited information and beyond the scope of the question anyway.

Comment: It works perfectly, I've just needed to change the nested component template to remove the ```<li>``` with his class by replacing them in the parent template as you said.
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

To make it the "Angular way", the approach needs to be changed.

Supposing that you have a collection of device names (`appareilNames`) returned from your component:

```
public get deviceNames(): Array<string> { ... }
```

The appropriate tags structure can be achieved as follows:

```js
<ul class="list-group">
  <li *ngFor="let deviceName of deviceNames"> <!-- iterate on each device name -->
    <app-appareil [appareilName]="deviceName"></app-appareil> <!-- use each name to create a component with it -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not what OP want. OP wants to hide `app-appareil` on build.

Comment: @SagarV I think that hiding it is not appropriate for this case, so I suggest changing the structure of the HTML.